# how to create 2 columns with repeated sequence of values in linux?

Tags: columns, numeric-data, seq

I want to create a 2 columns like:

```
1 10
1 20 
1 30
1 40
1 50
2 10
2 20
2 30 
2 40
2 50
3 10
3 20
3 30
3 40
3 50
```

any suggestion please?

Comment: @StephenHarris for first column I tried this: for i in {1..5}; do echo "1"; done
 but I have to repeat this 3 time. I am looking for a less time-consuming solution

Comment: -1 Because of lack of research effort.

Comment: @wjandrea I am in learning process. I do not understand what was wrong by this question, while it was really useful for me

Comment: @zara On StackExchange sites, you're expected to do your own research before turning to the community, and then to demonstrate the research you've done. I think you could have come up with an answer to this question if you had done some reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a recent version of Bash:

```
for i in {1..3}; do
    for j in {10..50..10}; do
        echo "$i $j"
    done
done
```

If you have an older version:

```
for i in {1..3}; do
    for j in {1..5}; do
        echo "$i ${j}0"
    done
done
```

Or, using `seq`:

```
for i in $(seq 1 3); do
    for j in $(seq 10 10 50); do
        echo "$i $j"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 6):

With modern shells you can combine [brace expansions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) and run stuff like:

```
printf %s\\n ID_{1..3}' '{10..50..10}
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation of [don_crissti's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/304316/116858) which just recognises the fact that the zero at the end is constant:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {1..3}' '{1..5}0
1 10
1 20
1 30
1 40
1 50
2 10
2 20
2 30
2 40
2 50
3 10
3 20
3 30
3 40
3 50
```